# Default CodeIgniter controller not working or is it my htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.13 and configured my htaccess file to remove "index.php" but when I try to go to a webpage it doesn't work unless I put the default controller in the URL.  Any advice?

Going to the following URLs work fine...

- https://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com/index.php
- https://www.example.com/welcome
- https://www.example.com/welcome/page/test

But the following URL does not work...

- https://www.example.com/page/test

How do I get this URL to work?

Here's my htaccess file...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

I changed my config.php to this...

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Here's my Welcome.php controller...

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{   
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('homepage', $data);
}

function page($pageName)
{
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view($pageName, '', TRUE);
    $this->load->view('template_page', $data);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a `Page` controller? If not: what does your `routes.php` file look like?

Comment: If `/welcome` and `/welcome/page/test` are working then the front-controller pattern in your `.htaccess` file is working just fine. (_Aside:_ However, you've put your `#force https` rule in the wrong place - this needs to go _before_ the CI front-controller rule.)

Comment: @Marleen No, I don't have a Page controller.  "page" is a function in the Welcome controller.  "welcome" is set as the default controller in the routes.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$route['default_controller']` only specifies which controller gets executed when the root directory of the website is requested. That is: when no `controller/method` subdirectory/string is given. In your example that would be when `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/index.php` are requested.

The default controller does not get executed when the requested url subdirectory/string starts with one of its methods.

For the `www.example.com/page/test` url to work, you need to either have a `Page` controller with a `test` method in it:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function test()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }

}
```

Or add the following to `config/routes.php` to have the `www.example.com/page/*` urls be handled by the `Welcome` controller's `page` method:

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'welcome/page/$1';
```